# permutations of lists sublists of various depth while keeping them separate on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iterator, combinations

I need to do permutations of sublists of various depth and keep them separate at the same time on Python. 
For example:

```
Input: x = [[a,b],[d],[e, [g,h]]

Output:  
[['a', 'b'], ['d'], ['e', ['g', 'h']]]
[['a', 'b'], ['d'], [['g', 'h'], 'e']]
[['b', 'a'], ['d'], ['e', ['g', 'h']]]
[['b', 'a'], ['d'], [['g', 'h'], 'e']]
[['a', 'b'], ['d'], ['e', ['h', 'g']]]
[['a', 'b'], ['d'], [['h', 'g'], 'e']]
[['b', 'a'], ['d'], ['e', ['h', 'g']]]
```

So i need to iterate over all sublists in sublists in sublists and so on....

I tried this, but it iterates over sublists of first level and does not permutate ['g','h'] part:

```
def product_perms(x):
    perms = [list(map(list,permutations(i))) for i in x]
    for x in product(*perms):
        print(list(x))
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
from collections import Counter
x = [['a','b','c'],['d'],['e','f',['g','h','i']]] 
def can_add(a, b):
    '''checks that the frequency of types in b is <= frequency of types in a'''
    c, d = Counter(map(type, a)), Counter(map(type, b))
    return all(c[k] >= j for k, j in d.items()) and all(isinstance(i, list) or i in a for i in b)

def combo(d, c = []):
   '''main recursive procedure'''
   def _combo(new_d, c = []):
      '''find combinations for individual list'''
      if len(c) == 2:
         yield c
      else:
         for i in filter(lambda x:x not in c, new_d):
            if isinstance(i, list):
               for k in combo(i):
                  if can_add(new_d, c+[k]):
                     yield from _combo(new_d, c+[k])
            else:
                if can_add(new_d, c+[i]):
                  yield from _combo(new_d, c+[i])
   if all(isinstance(i, list) for i in d):
      if len(d) == 1:
         if len(d[0]) == 1:
            yield d
         else:
            yield from map(lambda x:[x], _combo(d[0]))
      else:
         _r = list(combo(d[1:]))
         for i in ([d[0]] if len(d[0]) == 1 else _combo(d[0])):
           if _r:
             for b in _r:
               yield [i, *b]
           else:
              yield i
   elif d:
      yield from _combo(d)
```

---

```
_, *result = combo(x)
```

Sample output:

```
[[['a', 'b'], ['d'], ['e', ['g', 'h']]], 
 [['a', 'b'], ['d'], ['e', ['g', 'i']]], 
 [['a', 'b'], ['d'], ['e', ['h', 'g']]], 
 [['a', 'b'], ['d'], ['e', ['h', 'i']]], 
 [['a', 'b'], ['d'], ['e', ['i', 'g']]], 
 [['a', 'b'], ['d'], ['e', ['i', 'h']]], 
 ....
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, seems like recursion is a key. However i need to keep all elements in corresponding list, so [g, h, i] must always be in list together. The same with [a,b,c] and all other possible sublists

Comment: @EdZ Thank you for your comment. Solving that requirement is actually the job of the `can_add` function, which determines, based on the original list `a` and the generated permutation `b`, whether or not `b` is valid. You can update `can_add` to reflect this.

Comment: Yeah I tried to change can_add, but it didn't bring results. I don't quite get it)

Comment: I saw it, but the problem is that it gives things like this   [['a', 'b'], ['d'], [['g', 'h'], 'e']] where 'c', 'f' and 'i' are gone from their sublists. What I was trying to achieve are permutations of all elements within and across their sublist